# Drupal 7 Views filter criteria Entity Reference

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities

At the moment i'm making a drupal environment.

I'm trying to reach the following:

"Use a views to show my content types, but only the content types that have lets say "ads" as a field_type (Entity Refrence)."

Setup:

- Content Type: Packets

  - Title
  - Image
  - Entity Reference field_type to Content type: packets_types..

[image: Filter]

It gives me blank result.. the sort criteria is just working fine on thee Pakket_type

[image]

I've tried the Relationships, but this didn't changed anything for me.

If there is someone out there to help me, i would love that =)

Already thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if Im wrong but I think the problem is that Type Reference filed is actually node id.

What worked for me is the following:

1. Add a relationship from the Type Reference field.
2. Add the field you are trying to use as filter and use relationship from (1). Set your operator and value.
3. Profit!

P.S. It seems that using Taxonomy terms would be a better solution though i have no idea what you are trying to achive.

[image: Views setup]

Comment: I got it working by enabling in the Entity Reference the list feature,
but.. indeed i agree 200% with you, to use taxonomy instead. Just made it in taxonomy within 1 min, thanks for ya help =)